# Cannot connect to HIVE with Secured kerberos. I am using UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab()

Tags: jdbc, hive, kerberos

```
String driverName = "com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver";
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
info("Getting Connection"); 
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);    
info("Getting Connection"); `info("Getting Connection");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);


UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("****@***.***.COM","etc/****.keytab");
Class.forName(driverName); info("Getting Connection");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=EX‌​AMPLE.COM;KrbHostFQDN=hs2.example.com;KrbServiceName=hive");
info("Got Connection");
```

```
18:47:51,894 ERROR [1] Error in section Run at line unknown. An unexpected exception occurred in the script. Script section: Run. Caused by: LoginException occured. Unable to obtain Princpal Name for authentication 
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][HiveJDBCDriver](500164) Error initialized or created transport for authentication: CONN_KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_GET_TICKETCACHE.
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createTransport(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hive.api.ExtendedHS2Factory.createClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at script.run(script.java:85)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.IteratingVUser.run(IteratingVUser.java:351)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.internal.IteratingAgent.run(IteratingAgent.java:801)
Caused by: com.cloudera.hive.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][HiveJDBCDriver](500164) Error initialized or created transport for authentication: CONN_KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_GET_TICKETCACHE.
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.cloudera.hive.support.exceptions.GeneralException: CONN_KERBEROS_AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_GET_TICKETCACHE
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Princpal Name for authentication 
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Krb5LoginModule.java:733)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:629)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:542)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$5.run(LoginContext.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokeCreatorPriv(LoginContext.java:703)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:575)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.kerberos.Kerberos.getSubjectViaTicketCache(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createTransport(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hive.api.ExtendedHS2Factory.createClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at script.run(script.java:85)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.IteratingVUser.run(IteratingVUser.java:351)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.internal.IteratingAgent.run(IteratingAgent.java:801)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Please provide the piece of code you wrote, we can't help you with just a stacktrace

Comment: Sorry I will provide

Comment: Should I use a kinit. whats the kinit and beeline??

Comment: You should edit your question, not post your code in the comment section.. Maybe a quick visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can help you get started.

Answer (score 2):

Hive JDBC drivers don't use the Hadoop Auth libraries, because they are supposed to be able to connect from *outside* the cluster, with minimal dependencies on Hadoop libs.
So, in practise, your UGI settings are ignored.

But Hive JDBC drivers use the Thrift client libraries, which support **raw JAAS configuration for Kerberos auth**.

Sample use of system props on command-line:

```
java -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf \
     -Djava.security.auth.login.config=./my_jaas.conf \
     *****
```

Sample "my_jaas.conf" to get a private Kerberos ticket (not read from cache, not written to cache) with a password provided in a keytab file:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
    required
  useTicketCache=false
  doNotPrompt=true
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="file:/some/path/to/my_login.keytab"
  principal="my_login@MY.REALM"
  debug=true;
};
```

*Note that [the syntax above](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html) works with Sun/Oracle JDK and with OpenJDK, but not with IBM JDK which uses a different syntax...
It will not work either with the DataDirect connector (shipped with Oracle, IBM, Microstrategy etc.) which expects a specific "subject" in the conf.*

And that's it. The JDBC driver will automatically invoke JAAS when it detects that the URL requests a Kerberos connection, and JAAS will handle the dirty work.

PS: debugging security configuration issues is a hassle, but you have a couple of properties to enable the debug traces:

```
-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true
-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext
```

Comment: Please provide a complete information since I am new to HIVE. The above answer is helpful but  could you please provide the detail how the program will lokk like.

Comment: Look, dude, this is not a charity where experienced people agree to give free tutorship to dummies. Do your homework => spend some time on Google, experiment with Java code.

Comment: And in case you are really a dummy, the part where I say *"...And that's it. The JDBC driver will automatically invoke JAAS when it detects that the URL requests a Kerberos connection, and JAAS will handle the dirty work..."* really means that. You just need `Connection con =
 DriverManager.getConnection(urlWithExplicitKerberosInvocation);`

Comment: This is good info. However using debug I get >>>KinitOptions cache name is /tmp/krb5cc_0
java.sql.SQLException: [Cloudera][HiveJDBCDriver](500168) Error creating login context using ticket cache: Unable to obtain Principal Name for authentication .
But klist shows Ticket cache: KCM:0 not FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0 .
Therefore it fails to get the hive connection due to cache mismatch. On different server Ticket cache is: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0 the java code works fine to connect to hive. How do I make KCM cache into FILE cache in kinit? Since the java code wants to read ccache and not jaas.conf keytab.

Comment: The Java implementation of Kerberos has some limitations; the Hadoop-Auth library adds some more. AFAIK you **must** use a ticket cache of type `FILE:` -- in-memory cache services won't work https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/krb5-latest/doc/basic/ccache_def.html#ccache-types

Comment: bingo! you are a genius even after 5 years :) . Commented out KCM in the file /etc/krb5.conf.d/kcm_default_ccache and did kinit again shows Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0 . Immediately the java code worked and now dont even need jaas.conf just need driver HiveJDBC41.jar which probably means the DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://....) reads the kerberos ticket from the FILE: ccache and not jaas.conf.

Comment: JAAS conf has hard-coded defaults (depending on OS), with several things to try in cascade, and the last thing to try is... the OS-level cache. Not necessarily the default cache BTW, can be overriden via `$KRB5CCNAME` if you want "private" tickets _(e.g. when the same user runs different jobs with different creds)_