# Jmeter and hive jdbc security issue

Tags: hive, jmeter, kerberos

I'm trying to connect to hiveserver2 (v1.2) via Jmeter (v3.0). We're using Kerberos as authentication protocol on our cluster. I couldn't find proper configuration for Jmeter authentication parameters (which I beleive it's only jaas.conf). 
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768664/cannot-connect-to-hive-with-secured-kerberos-i-am-using-usergroupinformation-lo

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362326/connect-to-kerberised-hive-using-jdbc-from-remote-windows-system about the choice of JDBC drivers